# Is .NET 4.5 ready for use in production systems?

Tags: .net-4.5, production-environment

During my searches, I see tons of topics on .NET 4 / .NET 4.5 compatibility. I am taking over the development for multiple projects which were started back in 2004/2005 and are using .NET 2 - .NET 3 & 3.5.

I have the option to use .NET 4.5 - but I want to be sure it's safe to begin using in production systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

It was [released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/08/15/visual-studio-2012-and-net-framework-4-5-released-to-the-web.aspx) in 15-August-2012. More than enough to have it tested by early adopters.

Depending on your project, the best thing that you can do is changing the .NET version, deploy it to a new server and run all your automated and manual tests against it.